# How can I use group, inner join and sum?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sum

I have two Tables: **Products** & **Sales**.

**Products**

```
id- productname  -  grp

11    bmwblue       bmw
12    bmwwhite      bmw
13    audiblack     audi
14    audiwhite     audi
```

**Sales**

```
 id   productid  amount

 1      11        2
 2      12        1
 x      13        5
 x      14        3
```

How can I show;

audi 8, bmw 3 ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT grp,
       sum(amount) AS total_grp_amount
FROM products AS p
JOIN sales AS s ON p.id = s.product_id
GROUP BY grp
```

I guess you are looking for this.